# SQL Server SELECT paging with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I am selecting from a table and doing a left join with a many to one relationship.

My problem to solve is with paging. I want to do paging on tableA only.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
[WHERE HERE] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

This will return rows 0 - 9 of tableA. **Perfect**.

Now the problem is when I introduce the join. I still want tableA's rows 1-10 but when I do the join it introduces extra rows as expected since tableB will have multiple entries to join against each tableA row. So now I no longer get the same rows from tableA, I may only get the first 2 rows but have 10 total because of the join.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON foo = bar 
[WHERE HERE] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

I want to get back as many rows as the join produces but only on tableA's 0-9 (or 10-19)

To clarify, there are multiple tableB rows for each tableA row. I want to select and page based on tableA only but still get back an entry for all the joins on tableB.

Comment: Where is your ORDER BY? How do you determine "same" rows? What does "all the joins" mean?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  After asserting a total order to ensure you don't get duplicates, a brute-force way is to get the full set from the database and cut down the results (i.e., do the paging) in user code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use inner query in this case

```
SELECT *
   FROM (
   SELECT * FROM tableA [WHERE HERE] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
   ) q
JOIN tableB on foo = bar [WHERE HERE]
```

Comment: Interesting. I have a question. If my where clause on tableB only returns 5 rows agains't the 10 that tableA produced, wont this only give me 5 results back? When there may be a lot more matches if tableA wasn't first limited?

Comment: Yes, in that case only 5 rows will be returned. Wasn't that your requirement "I want to get back as many rows as the join produces but only on tableA's 0-9 (or 10-19)" ?

Comment: That is what I wrote, but what I want is to always get 10 rows from tableA. We will be consolidating the joins into single objects (the joins will be sub objects). So if we ask for rows 0-9 we want 10 objects in the end. Maybe I need to sit back and reword my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's gonna work with you query, cause this 0-10 fetch will be aplied to reults returned by the join. Did you tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableB on foo in 
    SELECT bar FROM tableA [WHERE HERE] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```